# How to resolve iptables error "Couldn't load match 'conntrack'" in docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, firewall, iptables

I have a Windows 10 host with Docker running. Inside Docker I run two Rust container. I would like to set up a Firewall inside one of them.

The Compose File:

```
version: '3'
services:
  outer-endpoint:
    image: rust:1.70
    ports:
      # host:container
      - 4488:4488
      - 4466:4466
    command: bash -c "apt update -y && apt upgrade -y &&
             tail -f /dev/null" # print line when file is updated, run container forever
    volumes: # bind mount
      - 'C:\Users\XXX'
  inner-endpoint:
    image: rust:1.70
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: bash -c "apt update -y && apt upgrade -y &&
             apt install iptables -y &&
             tail -f /dev/null"
    volumes:
      - 'C:\Users\XXX'
    cap_add: # allow iptables
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
```

I get inside the Container with

```
docker exec -it containername bash
```

There I use the following commands:

I use

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

to deny incoming traffic. That works well.
But when I try

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

to allow incoming traffic for established and related connections, I get the following error:

```
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): Couldn't load match `conntrack':No such file or directory
```

I do not understand what causes the error. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Retry with **sudo**

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install conntrack in your docker image.

Comment: I installed it 'apt install conntrack', but the error remains. Do you have any further suggestions?